# Why some line lasers of power less than $\rm 1mW$ is brighter than that rated for higher power?

Tags: laser, light-emitting-diodes

I want make a line laser that uses 1mW power and should be visible at a distance of 10 m.

I have a locally available laser module of 5mW which barely reaches 5 meters whereas Bosch GLL5-50X claims to use <1mW class 2 laser and it is visible at 15 meters also.

I have very little knowledge about lasers but I would like to know the technique they used.
I could not find it on google too, if anyone knows any blog or site than please share.

Comment: what do you mean by "should be visible at distance" and "barely reaches 5m"?

Comment: By "barely reaches 5m" I meant it is not visible after that. There is huge difference between both laser visibilty and I am interested in knowing why and how.

Comment: I mean, are you at 5m from a wall, or just shooting it in the air, or is the laser 5m from the wall, but you are next to the wall. Bosch says its laser system projects a line on the wall and the projector has to be <15m from the wall. This means that workers at the wall would see the line. However these measurements are highly subjective as external lighting conditions affect strongly the perceived brightness. As you can imagine at night it would be extremely easy to see the line.

Comment: I am actually shooting it at floor at 45 degrees so I can see line on floor. I forget to mention that I am talking about line laser.

Comment: Are you trying to look at it from 5m away or are you trying to see it while next to the line? Are you indoors or outdoors? Did you compare your diode to the GLL5-50X in person, or you are just assuming it would be visible in your conditions from its spec sheet? If your diode is 650~660nm, it will be less visible than a 635~640nm one. Your diode might be rated for 5mW but maybe its output is way less. If your diode is badly collimated, it will also affect strongly its size and visibility depending on scattering distance